# OGR GetX returns always zero

Tags: gdal, ogr

I am trying to get the first x-coordinates of a polygon. However I only get zero in return. What could cause that?

```
import os, sys, gdal, ogr
from gdalconst import *

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
testarea = driver.Open('testarea.shp', 0)
testarealyr = testarea.GetLayer()
testareafeature = testarealyr.GetNextFeature()

# get the x,y coordinates for the point
testareageom = testareafeature.GetGeometryRef()
print testareageom

x = testareageom.GetX()
print x


>>> 
POLYGON ((-124.1963006330602 43.006410659375554,-124.1861022086067 43.006647759060762,-124.1858958821004 43.00274627515271,-124.19612378176909 43.002422936639086,-124.19612378176909 43.002422936639086,-124.1963006330602 43.006410659375554))
0.0
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe its only to be used with point geometries? I have only used it with points, and it then works fine for me.

Comment: yes that was the reason.

Comment: don't cross-post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54140/ogr-getx-returns-always-zero